# GET request to server returns net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, xhtml

Hello I'm new at web developing so I apologize if my methods/questions makes no sense.

I am trying to load an audio file from a server directory to an audio html element. I was following fetch data example in this [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', http://*ipAddress*/audioUpload/test.mp3, true, *serverUsername*, *serverPassword*);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {

    var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'mp3'});
    var audioReader = new FileReader();
    audioReader.onload = function(d) {
      var e = document.createElement("audio");
      e.src = d.target.result;
      e.id = "audioHTMLId";
      e.setAttribute("type", 'mp3');
      e.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
      e.setAttribute("autoplay", "true");
      document.getElementById("container").appendChild(e);
    }
    audioReader.readAsDataURL(blob);               
  }
};

xhr.send();
```

}

However I am getting this statement in console log:

```
GET http://*ipAddress*/audioUpload/test.mp3 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

And don't know why.

Also I was wondering if there were a better way to play/get audio files on client's audio html element for large mp3 files (1-1.5 hour long)?

Comment: This is the browser's http client telling you that it was unable to reach the server at all.

Comment: I see, thank you for the quick response. Would you happen to know why might I not able to reach the server? I'm pretty sure the ipAddress and file location is correct.

Comment: Well can you actually reach the URL when you open it up with curl or the browser? 

Even then, the browser security settings might still not allow you to make XHR requests to a remote URL unless the server responds with proper CORS headers.

Comment: Better way to load large mp3 files: use the `<audio>` tag, it supports streaming.

Comment: Have you tried going to the URL directly from your address bar?

Comment: have you double checked the username password being passed to the GET method

Comment: @Gremash Yes I got a webpage not found screen. But I assumed that if I used the .open() with server username / password I would be able to access the files.

Comment: @faljbour yes it's the same password and username used in accessing the server through the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Is this by chance in Chrome? I've send this when you try and send a request and the server disconnects. This can be HTTPS / SSL related, or a problem with the actual server . I'd check whether or not you can actually hit the file like so:

```
wget http://*ipAddress*/audioUpload/test.mp3
```

It could be that said server is actually unreachable from wherever your environment is.

As for the second half of your question, you might just want to upload the audio to youtube and embed it, rather than dealing with the hassle of dealing with it yourself (storage, bandwidth, etc). However, I'm sure someone more versed than I could give you a better answer on that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the authorization headers manually:

```
....
xhr.open('GET', http://*ipAddress*/audioUpload/test.mp3, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(*serverUsername* + ":" + *serverPassword*))
....
```

Comment: I still get the same error. Maybe I am not understanding how accessing a server works. Does the server directory where the files are needs to be publicly accessible even with the user/pass? I have root access for the server as well if that helps.